# Set node attributes on node in jstree

Tags: jstree

When I load the tree I load it using the following snippet:

```
{"data":"admin","state":"closed","metadata":{"id":"\/admin\/","type":"default"}
```

When I grab a referenced to a particular chosen node I use:

```
jQuery.data(data.rslt.obj[0], "jstree").id;
```

However, when I add a new node, i'm not sure how to set the id of the new node.  I've seen some examples that say to use the following:

```
var newnode = data.rslt.obj;
newnode.attr("id", new_node_id);
```

Where new_node_id is generated by me, but this doesn't seem to work.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I just use the provided method from the CRRM documentation:

`$("#treeContainer").jstree("create", parentNode, "position", {attr: {id: your_generated_id ...}, data: "nodeTitle"} ,null, true);`

Works like a charm for me.

Comment: How do you grab a reference to the parentNode?

Comment: If you pass `null` it's the currently selected node, but I use a jQuery selector or an event handler to reference the parent. For example:
`$('ul > li#' +parentId)`, or give each node a specific class, and then backtrack from a given event `.closest('.structureNode')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using json data to populate your tree, then you should supply it in the json string:
[see the docu](http://www.jstree.com/docs/json/)